# How does ampersand in the return type of a function declaration work?

Tags: c++, function, function-declaration

In this piece of code, why f() is declared as "double & f(..."? What does it mean and how does it work? I don't even know what to google to find the answer to my question. Please help.

```
double a = 1, b = 2;
double & f (double & d) {
    d = 4;
    return b;
}
```

I know ampersand sign means the address of a variable or a function, but I don't see why it would make sense to write it when you are declaring a function.

Comment: No. The ampersand in your case (in that context) indicates a reference.

Comment: Further the ampersand it indicates a reference in *every* appearance in this code snippet.

Comment: Btw, titles including the words "this function" or "this code" are hardly useful. Think of future users who have a similar question and want to find it in SO -- just like you weren't able to find what you were looking for. They are not likely to search for "this function" when the problem they have is best described as "ampersand in return type" or similar.

Comment: @jogojapan Changed the title, thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

When the `&` operator is used in a declaration form, preceded by a type it doesn't mean "the address of" but a "reference to" which is essentially an automatically dereferenced pointer with disabled pointer arithmetic.

There are no references in C, so if you want to pass or return by reference, you had to pass a const pointer and dereference it to access the pointed to value. C++ added references to make this concept easier, to prevent accidental walking off the address with pointer arithmetic, and to save the need to dereference the pointer. This makes working with it much easier and resulting in cleaner and more readable syntax.

Answer (score 32):

Consider these two functions: `power2()` and `add()`:

```
void power2 (double& res, double x) {
    res = x * x;
}

double& add (double& x) {
    return ++x;
}
```

The first computes the power of `x` and stores the result in the first argument, `res`, – it does not need to return it.

The second returns a reference, which means this reference can later be assigned a new value.

Example:

```
    double res = 0;

    power2(res, 5);
    printf("%f\n", res);


    printf("%f\n", ++add(res));
```

Output:

```
25.000000
27.000000
```

Please note that the second output is `27`, not 26 – it's because of the use of `++` inside the `printf()` call.

Comment: +1 for concrete examples

Comment: I am not trying to be rude, but that example is rather difficult to comprehend

Comment: @puk It's not rude at all. It'd be more helpful though if you proposed an idea on making it more digestible. You can also post your own answer if you feel there is an easier way that is so fundamentally different it wouldn't make sense to edit this answer.

Comment: It might be more helpful to point out that this isn't valid: `int& foo() { return 0; }`

Answer (score 6):

In this case, the ampersand does *not* mean taking an address, but it denotes a reference. Here, `f` is a function that takes a reference to double as parameter and returns a reference to double.

You might want to read about C++'s references in your textbook of choice, since they are a very basic part of the language.