# What does ClassName& as a return type mean?

Tags: c++, pointers, syntax, types, return-type

I try to understand the following code (taken from [here](http://ootips.org/yonat/4dev/smart-pointers.html)):

```
template <class T> class auto_ptr
{
    T* ptr;
public:
    explicit auto_ptr(T* p = 0) : ptr(p) {}
    ~auto_ptr()                 {delete ptr;}
    T& operator*()              {return *ptr;} // <----- The problematic row.
    T* operator->()             {return ptr;}
    // ...
};
```

I cannot understand what do we mean when we use `T&` as a return type of a function. If `T` is a pointer to an integer (or any other type), then I would interpret `T&` as integer (or any other corresponding type). But in the above given code `T` is not a pointer. `T` is a class, and one of its members (`ptr`) is a pointer to objects of this class but `T` is not a class of pointers. So, what does `T&` as a return type mean?

Comment: This is extremely basic C++, and you should probably consult a book rather than SO for the mechanical details of the language. For any non-reference type `T`, `T &` denotes a reference to a `T`.

Comment: If `T` is `int *` then `T&` is `int * &`.

Comment: Answered many times: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15106690/how-does-ampersand-in-the-return-type-of-a-function-declaration-work/15106932#15106932

Comment: It's probably best not to study `auto_ptr` in too much detail. It's a quirky, dangerous type that is deprecated in modern C++.

Comment: As Kerrek says, you'd best start with a good book. There's a [handy list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) here on SO.

Answer (score 3):

It means the same as outside the context of a function's return type, i.e. `T&` is a *reference* to `T`. In this case, the function returns a reference to an object of type `T` that the caller can use to observe (and also alter, if `T` is not `const`-qualified) the referenced object.

Answer (score 0):

`T&` is simply a *reference* to type `T`. the function returns a reference to an object of class `T`.

Answer (score 0):

> T is a class, and one of its members (ptr) is a pointer to objects of this class but T is not a class of pointers.

`ptr` is not a member of class `T`. It is a member of class `auto_ptr<T>`.
`ptr` *is* a pointer to `T`. But the fact that `T` is not a "class of pointers"
(whatever that means) does not prevent something being a pointer to a `T`.

`std::string` is a class - of strings, not pointers.

`std::string str;` is an object of class `std::string`.

`&str` is the address of `str`

```
std::string * ps = &str;
```

is a pointer to an `std::string`.

From the top:

`template <class T> class auto_ptr` is a class template whose sole
template parameter is `class T`. You *instantiate* the template by specifying
some actual class for `T` and declaring some object of the resulting type:

```
auto_ptr<std::string> aps;
```

That gives you another actual class, "auto-pointer-to-string", which is
exactly like:

```
class auto_ptr_to_string
{
    std::string * ptr;
public:
    explicit auto_ptr(std::string * p = 0) : ptr(p) {}
    ~auto_ptr()                 {delete ptr;}
    std::string & operator*()   {return *ptr;}
    std::string * operator->()  {return ptr;}
    // ...
};
```

And `aps` is an object defined like that.

The class has a data member `ptr`, which is a pointer to an `std::string`.

The class also has an operator:

```
std::string & operator*()   {return *ptr;}
```

This operator defines the behaviour that results from
applying the '*'-prefix to an object of type `auto_ptr<std::string>`,
e.g.`*aps`.

The definition of the operator tells you that it returns a reference to
an `std::string`, and that the `std::string` referred to by this reference is 
`*ptr`, which means "the one referred to by the data member `ptr`".

So:

```
auto_ptr<std::string> aps(new std::string("Get it?"));
```

constructs an `auto_ptr<std::string>` called `aps` and the constuctor
initializes the data member `aps.ptr` with a pointer to a dynamically
allocated `std::string` containing "Get it?".

And:

```
std::string s = *aps;
```

according to the definition of `auto_ptr<std::string>::operator*()`,
declares an `std::string` `s` and initializes it with the `std::string`
referred to by `aps.ptr`, namely that one containing "Get it?"

Finally the `class T` syntax for template parameters does not actually
restrict their values to classes: `auto_ptr<int>`, for example, is fine,
though `int` is not a class type. And I reiterate Mike Seymour's comment
about `auto_ptr` being a bad old thing.